Warning: Attempt to read property "game_id" on int
I have 2 tables, shows and games.

shows has show_id as primary key.
games has game_id as primary key.

I am trying to select all game_ids that have show_id = $show_id.
I am using huge/panique on GitHub.
It has controllers, models, views.
Here is my controller code:
public function details($show_id)
    {
        $this->View->render('shows/details', array(
            'venues' => VenuesModel::getVenue($show_id),
            'payment_types' => AdminModel::getPaymentTypes(),
            'products' => AdminModel::getAllProducts(),
            'games' => ShowsModel::getAllGames($show_id)
        ));
    }

Here is my Model Code:
public static function getAllGames($show_id)
    {
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        $sql = 
        "SELECT * FROM 
        games
        WHERE show_id = :show_id"
        ;
        $query = $database->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(
            ':show_id' => $show_id
        ));

        // fetch() is the PDO method that gets a single result
        return $query->fetch();
    }

Here is my view:  (url - shows/details/$show_id)
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">game_id (primary key)</th>
      <th scope="col">show_id</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach ($this->games as $game) { ?>
                 <td><?= $game->game_id; ?></td>
                 <td><?= $game->show_id; ?></td>
                 
  </tr>
               <?php } ?>
  
  </tbody>
</table>

The Error I'm getting:
Warning: Attempt to read property "game_id" on int in /home/foxtangocharlie/a.xftc.co/application/view/shows/details.php on line 20

and
Warning: Attempt to read property "show_id" on int in /home/foxtangocharlie/a.xftc.co/application/view/shows/details.php on line 21

I have created numerous lists that have worked. But those did not have a "where" with URL parameter.

Presumably this is on the $game object. Inspect that, see what it is and work your way backwards.

There is class controller and class model. Controller has objects (i guess) that render views, like the details page, as well as perform actions, like edit/save.  The class model holds the mysql queries. basically.  I would assume that all the games from a specific show is an object. I am amateur. doing my best.

I'm mostly ignoring the class itself, and focusing on the variable. You want it to be something, but what is it?

I have no idea.  I am using a platform that I didn't build.  I do not know code.  But I have been able to copy and paste and modify to suit my needs. up to this point. I don't know enough to be able to break it down and work backwards.  I wish i knew. I just don't.

We don't know your custom application, either.

PHP has a lot of debugging functions, such as var_dump(). I would start by using that on $game. It most likely is going to say it is an int. So then you should repeat it on $this->games.

Reading your code further, the fetch method is for a single row, you want to call fetchAll to get all rows.

That was it!!  I can't believe i missed that.  Thank you all for your input... and eyes.
